# Simplify Graph by combining edges python-igraph

Tags: python-3.x, igraph

I am aiming to simplify my graph with milions of edges in a conceptually very simple way but cannot find an easy way how to do it.

ex:

```
b -> c *-> d1 -> d2 ->* e -> f
a -> c *-> d1 -> d2 ->* e -> g
<>
b -> c *->* e -> f
a -> c *->* e -> g
```

I would like to merge all edges following this condition:

- if the node in between two edges has a degree equal to 2 than delete node and merge edges

Which is diferent from the igraph method: `igraph.Graph.simplify()`.

(without having to rebuild the entire graph if possible).

The aim is to have the smallest possible graph to perform pathfinding algorithms on it quicker.

Comment: With "merging", I assume that you mean you would like to contract the vertices along that path, but without keeping multiple edges (i.e.  `c`, `d1`, and `d2` should be contracted in your example, but the self-loop should not be included). However, the question is not entirely clear to me. What if you have `c *-> d1 -> d2 ->* e` and `c *-> h1 -> h2 ->* e`? Should both paths be "simplified" to a single `c -> e` edge, or not?

Comment: yes they should be "simplified" in that case (keeping 'path' with lowest cost over the sum of weight);
what i want is to only keep nodes with 1 edge or  3 and more  edges (everything except 2) that way i keep all branching options for pathfinding and endpoints of the network (node with 1 edge) while reducing the number of edges and nodes

Comment: You mean everything with 1 outgoing and 1 incoming edge? What about sources or sinks with 2 edges (outgoing or incoming)?

Comment: i need to keep dead-ends (1 incoming or outgoing edge) otherwise, i will lose some important entrypoints into the graph. (And otherwise the graph will collapse until the only things remaining are all the graph's cycles). my graph is undirected so in my graph there are no sinks and sources with multiple edges if the node has more than 1 edge than it is just an intermediate node

Comment: You are welcome to open a feature request for this. @VincentTraag I have this implemented in IGraph/M as [IGSmoothen](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igsmoothen). It is indispensable for working with some kinds of spatial networks. We can reuse some of the C++ code I wrote for that.

Comment: Be aware that this operation will create non-simple graphs (multi-edges and self-loops). "Simplify" is not really an ideal name for it.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes that is exactly what i am trying to do. And multi-edges and self-loops won't cause any issues with pathfinding so that's fine with me. Anyway they can easily be identified and removed if needed

Comment: @LouisCottereau The feature request should be added for the C core of igraph, here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/new/choose Please fill out all sections, and explain your use case, as well as other potential use cases. This helps us prioritize the task. It's also good practice to document uses cases, as it help understand needs better.

Comment: I wonder how many degree-2 nodes you have that you would expect a noticeable speedup in pathfinding, and how you obtained such a network (with so many deg-2 nodes).

Comment: I am using the national road network of my country, because of restrictions i have removed from it highways and smaller local roads. So I end up with only regional roads however these roads are heavily segmented because of where the local roads were connected. so out of over 500 000 nodes, more than 400 000 are deg-2 nodes